# Assign a default value for every coming int in the method

Tags: c#, sql, oop

i have two methods having

```
 getlisting(string url,int ID)
```

i want to pass this ID to another method in another class,

```
class cc=new class();
cc.updatevalue(ID);
```

now i want to pass this int value to that updatevalue method and assign it a 0 value. and every time getlisting having different ID and passing it to update method. i have tried if else condition as well. so my question is can anyone help me in assigning that default 0 value to every coming int value.
after assigning i want to update that in my DataTable

```
 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID ='ID'", obj.openConnection());
```

and ID is throwing an error of cannot convert varchar into data type, tell me the condition with which i can give default value to every int and makes it equal to ID. thanks

Comment: Your question is not very clear, but in case you want a new unique value for each new record, you might want to look at IDENTITY feature of SQL Server table columns.

Comment: it's not kinda sql thingy,i am asking which condition should i apply so i can give default value myself to every dynamic/different int that i am receiving from another method and then pass it to table,

Comment: Problem is with your `SQL` query,you need to pass valid `ID` value instead of `ID` string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with your `SQL`, also I suggest using parameterized query , so your code should be...

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status=@status WHERE ID =@id", obj.openConnection());

cmd.Parameters.Add("@status", SqlDbType.Int).Value = 1; // modify this to varchar if status is string
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ID;
```

On the side note, we could specify default value for parameters take a look at [`Named and Optional Arguments`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx).

Comment: ok thanks dear but i have tried this earlier i think the problem is with my assigning value i am assigning through if else condition and i am having a different ID value every time from getlisting method

Comment: your code works,but i need to know how it can handle every different value, ok wait

Comment: public void UpdatePaging(int ID,int Status)
        {
            if (ID !=null)
            {
                //assign zero
            }
            else if(ID > 0)
            {
                //assign zero
            }
            else
            {
                //assign desired value
            }
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID =@id", obj.openConnection());
  //i am doing it because selecting values from that table and which i already select i want there status to be 1 and ID as well 1 or zero, so my code won't select them again @Hari help?

Comment: What do you want use when `ID<=0`?

Comment: every value will be greater than zero and i want to assign 0 to every ID value, so my data table won't select data against this value again, my if else is not working well i can see, tell me if there is any other way to assigning zero to every ID, whether i am getting 67 or 74 it should be assigned zero and in table too

Comment: every ID is starting from 1 and so on and those value which are already used in this method i want to assign them zero value

Comment: i have 77 values in my table having status 0 and ID from 1 to so on, i am selecting those values through my data table and in my getlisting(string url, int ID) method i am using those values one by one, i want that when that value came one by one they should be assigned a value zero and store into table again so my data table won't select those value because obviously they will be of Status 1 and ID zero, and i am selecting value > than 1 and status 0, tell me please how to assign zero value to every ID in updatePaging(int ID) in paging i am having ID from getlisting() method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109983/discussion-between-shah-rukh-and-hari-prasad).

Answer (score -1):

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Paging SET Status='1' WHERE ID ='" . ID . "'", obj.openConnection());
```

You were passing ID as the string 'ID' instead of your variable.